# Can I Import an Excel Spreadsheet into iWork Pages?

Tags: iwork-pages

I'm working on a document that has to be created in iWork's Pages program.  As part of the document I need to add some data from an Excel spreadhsheet.  I know that in MS Office I can copy and paste an Excel sheet into a Word document.  I tried the same process in Pages, but without success.  The pasted document was formatted differently and the text and spreadhseet boxes were significantly larger - to the point where most of the spreadsheet was not visible on the Pages page.  BTW, both the Pages and Excel are the latest versions of the software as of September 2012.

And suggestions and advice you can offer would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Not directly (without the formatting problems you've found), but there are some workarounds.

Here's one (found [on Apple's forums](https://discussions.apple.com/message/778131#778131)):

> - Copy the cells in Excel.
> - Goto Preview.app, choose File->New from Pasteboard (command-N).
> - Copy into clipboard (command-C).
> - Paste into Pages. You can then discard the content in Preview.

And [another](https://discussions.apple.com/message/778127#778127):

> - Paste the cells back into Excel itself first.
> - Copy the cells.
> - Press  (to disable the walking ants around the copied cells).
> - Choose Paste Special > Picture.
> - Copy the picture.
> - Paste into Pages.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks very much for your prompt help.  Both of the above suggestions worked.  Much appreciated!

Comment: No problem. Feel free to mark it as accepted. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Pages 5.5.1.

Create a chart by clicking on the Chart icon at the top of the page:
[image]

The chart will appear, add or delete rows and columns so that the chart has the same number of rows/columns as your excel sheet.  Click on the [image] icon to add/remove rows, click on the [image] icon to add/remove columns.

Copy your data from excel, click on Cell A1 in the Pages table and paste data.  Merged rows and centering won't be transferred so you'll have to redo that and other formatting.  Some formatting like bold text will transfer.

Formulas don't transfer either which sucks, but you can copy/paste the actual formula as long as the cell numbers match up between Excel and Pages.

Answer (score 0):

With the others solution you'll get a raster image of the table. Instead if you want to keep the text of the table editable you can do in the following way:

- In Pages create a new table with the same number (or more) of rows and columns of the table you want to copy (If your table has a lot of rows you can select multiple rows, right-click and choose one of the 'add rows..' option).
- Select all the rows you want to copy in the Numbers sheet
- In Pages select all the rows you created and paste

Tested with Numbers 3.5.3 and Pages 5.5.3.

Answer (score -2):

Those did not work for me.  So

1. I imported from excel into word.
2. Cleaned it up a bit, then save as word.
3. Open Pages and then open your word doc in pages.

The only reason I do this is I have some spreadsheets that I want to hyperlink, and exporting to pdf from Word or Excel on Mac loses the link.  So now I work them in Pages.
Probably could do the same in numbers but I seem to be able to get a nicer format in Pages.